# Failure executing the send pipeline in Biztalk 2006 R2 using HL7

Tags: biztalk, hl7, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-pipelines

We have a strange problem. I added a couple of new schema's and orchestrations similar to ones we already had, and redeployed. The thing is, we recently upgraded to SP1 BizTalk 2006R2 and I'm not really sure if this is the cause of our problem.

I get an error like this:

> There was a failure executing the send pipeline: "blablabla.pipeline, blablabla, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bf4bb7b2a02e5c5f" Source: "BTAHL7 2.X Assembler" Send Port: "toFDW" URI: "192.168.100.1:8008" Reason: Value cannot be null.
>       Parameter name: parent

Now the thing is, this is only for the messages where I add an extra filter. On the port I filter for a couple of message types and for one type there's an extra filter on a promoted property. In the orchestration this type gets the promoted property true an xpath expression, for all the other types there is no promoted property. However I get this error on our sendport, even if I don't set the extra filter. So I'm guessing that the BTAHL7Pipeline (HL7 Adapter) is having problems with the promoted property I set through xpath code. However we have always done this and with all the other orchestrations and messages this doesn't give a problem.

So I'm guessing it's related to our SP1 installation, but I'm not quite sure. Does anyone has an idea what's going or had a similar problem?

*Edit:* I did the same thing on another server which also has SP1 etc, and it's working here. Only this is the develop server so does anyone have any idea what setting or config could be wrong on the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with the BTAHL7, according to Microsoft. Might that be the issue? Details are [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979146).

Looks like it has to do with the BTAHL7 MSH overrides configuration...